# Sympy diffgeom: Metric dependent on function

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I'm having problems defining a metric using sympy's diffgeom package, where the metric depends on a function `f(x,y)`.

I get the error `ValueError: Can't calculate 1st derivative wrt x.`

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.diffgeom import Manifold, Patch, CoordSystem

m = Manifold("M",2)
patch = Patch("P",m)
cartesian = CoordSystem("cartesian", patch, ["x", "y"])
x, y = cartesian.coord_functions()
f = sym.Function('f')
xi = sym.Symbol('xi')

g = sym.Matrix([
    [ xi + sym.diff(f,x)**2         , sym.diff(f,x) * sym.diff(f,y) ],
    [ sym.diff(f,x) * sym.diff(f,y) , xi + sym.diff(f,y)**2 ]   
])
```

I have a feeling it's because of how `x` and `y` are defined, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, differentiation with respect to these x and y (objects of class sympy.diffgeom.diffgeom.BaseScalarField) is not supported. You can see this by accessing the internal property `_diff_wrt` which indicates if something can be a thing with respect to which to differentiate.

```
>>> x._diff_wrt
False
```

Do those derivative (with respect to a scalar field) make mathematical sense here? I'm not sure.

An additional issue is that SymPy does not differentiate functions, so

```
f = Function('f')
diff(f, x)
```

is always an error. SymPy can differentiate expressions, e.g., `diff(f(x, y), x)`.

Aside: `diff` can be used as a method of an expression, which in your case would result in shorter code, like `f(x, y).diff(x)`.